# LINQ First() or Single() parameter

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Trying to get sorted data from CSV file. This code works fine except "Side" column which is string and is same for one group. I can't figure out what parameter should be for Single() of First() methods.

```
    var stuff = from line in File.ReadLines(@"d:\tmp\4.csv").Skip(1)
                    let columns = line.Split(';')
                    select new
                    {
                        Time = columns[0],
                        Side = columns[2],
                        Qty = columns[3],
                        Symbol = columns[4],
                        Price = columns[5],
                    };

        var sorted = from line in stuff
                     group line by new { line.Time, line.Symbol }
                         into category
                         select new {
                             category.Key.Time,
                             category.Key.Symbol, 
                             Qty = category.Sum(p => Int32.Parse(p.Qty)),
                             Price = category.Average(p => double.Parse(p.Price)),
                             Side = ?????? };
```

Comment: add line.Side in your group query like line.Time, line.Symbol, line.Side and then read it like Side = Category.Key.Side

Comment: @NoOne Thank you! But is it possible to get Side similar way as Qty and Price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Single` will throw an exception if it finds more than one record, I think it is not what you want

`First`  select the first record from the list, but Both `Single`  and  `First` will throw an 'InvalidOperationException' exception if the collection is empty.

So I would use `FirstOrDefault` here

```
Side = category.Select(p => p.Side).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: This causes
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: What are the values in csv as `Side`?

Comment: Strings. "B" or "S". But it even doesn't compile because of Side = category.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Side)

Comment: If side = "B" it prints whole member again after side: {time =... symbol = ..., qty = ..., price = ..., Side = {time=...., Side= B, Qty =.. Price = ......           If not "B" it prints empty after Side =.  How can we just take the Side string without checking anything?

Comment: That's works! I was trying something like that but got errors. Thanks!